# Python decorator that can be also used as stand-alone function

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I'm quite new to decorators and I'm trying to build a decorator with an argument that should work both as a decorator and a stand-alone function. The basic idea is to raise an error if some condition is not satisfied. Example:

```py
ensure_condition("fail") # exception should be raised
ensure_condition("pass") # nothing should happen

@ensure_condition("fail") # check condition before every `func` call
def f1():
    return 1
```

I thought about doing this:

```py
def ensure_condition(arg: str):
    if not _validate(arg):
        raise Exception("failed")

    def ensure_condition_decorator(f = lambda *_: None):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return ensure_condition_decorator
```

But the above results in the `_validate` function being called also when the `f1` function is declared (not only executed).

Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Your decorator will never be able to detect whether it is going to be used stand-alone, or as a decorator of another function.

Comment: This is a job for two functions, not one.

Comment: Anyway if you wish to call the ensure_condition not as a decorator you will need to do `ensure_condition("fail")()()`

Comment: Or in the ensure_condition definition pass an optional argument which says `stand_alone=False` and for stand alone use case you can pass it as `True` and exit the function based on that